# Writing GPX-File to Google Drive and open with APP

Tags: google-apps-script, gpx

I am using a script to produce a file with GPS-Data...GPX-File. Now I am searching for the applicable MIME TYPE.

```
  var alumnopath = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var folderalumno = alumnopath.hasNext() ? 
  alumnopath.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(foldername);

  //This creates a file in the folder
  var file = folderalumno.createFile(filename + '.gpx', TRK, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
```

TRK is the content of the file (the GPS-Data).

Due to lack of other options I am using MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT.

**The problem:** If I open the produced GPX-File out of my Google-Drive-App on my Smartphone, the file opens as text-file instead of opening directly an appropriate APP (such as Outdooractive, OruxMaps, etc.) for navigation.

When I modify the file (doesn't matter what...just doing minor stuff) and safe it again, it works as expected (opening a navigation app).

**My question:** How can I tell Google Drive that the file has to be treated as a GPX-File that has to be opened by navigation apps?

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile I found the solution myself.

I just replaced **MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT** by **application/gpx+xml**

`var file = folderalumno.createFile(filename + '.gpx', TRK, 'application/gpx+xml');`

Comment: You mentioned using `var blob = Utilities.newBlob(TRK, 'application/gpx+xml', filename + '.gpx');`  to create a blob in the Apps Script group.

Comment: Yes, I use it for sending the GPX-File by Mail. There are two ways to get the GPX-File in my script...one is by Google Drive, the other is by GMail (blob)